# Drag and drop in Selenium Web driver Java script

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Drag and drop** in selenium Java script,

It may sounds repetitive. But,
As per the docs available in https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/ found below two approaches and tried both of them.

```
await driver.actions().
             dragAndDrop(source, destination).
             perform();
```

Second Approach

```
await new ActionSequence
                .ActionSequence(driver)
                .mouseDown(source)
                .mouseMove({x: 102, y: 516})
                .mouseUp()
                .perform();
```

Tried with both Web element and off-set location as well. But no luck.

There isn't any error or exception at time of execution. Execution goes smooth without drag and drop happening

The identificator used are correct and properly defined, able to perform other operations like click using same identificators

Tested on the sample test web site https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxTree/samples/05_drag_n_drop/01_drag_in_simple.html

I hope there isn't any issue with web site as I am able to perform drag and drop on the same web site using selenium-java

any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Hi @Bhargav Marpu, what do you want to drag and drop in that site?

Comment: Hi @Ali CSE, Below info text "Try to drag any element and drop it on the tree" there is a tree menu where elements are draggable, drag and drop operation on any element is fine